# comparing indexes in an array swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of numbers and I want to check if the number in the `index 1` is equal to number in `index 2` and if yes, I want to increase my counter by 1. I have tried all I can but could not come up with the proper logic

this is what I have tried so far

```
let c: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

for (index, val) in c.enumerated() {
        print(val)
        var counts = 0
        if c.firstIndex(of: index) == c.index(after: index) {
            print("yes")
            counts += 1
            print(counts)
        }
    }
```

so comparing 0 `index 0` to 0 `index 1` counter increase by 1,
then 0 `index 1` to 0 `index 2` counter increase by 1,
then 0 `index 2` to 0 `index 3` counter increase by 1
then 0 `index 3` to 1 `index 4`  skip,
then 0 `index 3` to 0 `index 5` counter increase by 1

Comment: yes. if they are not, you jump that value and compare to the next one that is equal for the preceding value

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: the values can only be 0 and 1

Comment: All but the last 0 and the last 1 are followed by an identical number, so you can simply return `c.count - 2` (assuming that there are both zeros and ones in the array, otherwise it is `c.count - 1`)

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: answer for `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` is 4 and answer for `0 0 0 0 1 0` it is 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191609/discussion-between-martin-r-and-king).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem at hand

The particular issue in your case is that `c.firstIndex(of: index)` finds the first index of `index` in `c`. I think you meant to write  `c.firstIndex(of: val)`, but even that won't work. For example, if you ask `c.firstIndex(of 0)`, it will always give you `0`, even if you're midway through the array, because the first `0` element is always at index `0`, in your test case.

Another issue is that your `count` is in the loop scope, which means every iteration gets its own independent `count` variable, initialized to `0`, which will at most ever be incremented to `1`, before being reinitialized.

### A cleaner solution

This is an ideal case for a more functional style. It's much simpler, but also quite element.

The solution is a chain of 4 steps:

1. Use the `zip(a, a.dropFirst())` pattern, which for an array `a` consisting of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, will produce an array of pairs of adjacent elements, like `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]`
2. From there, it's a matter of checking each of the pairs to see if their two elements are the same. If so, we change them into a `0`, otherwise a `1`.
3. Then we just sum these numbers to obtain the final result.
4. Ideally, we  package this code into a function, and make it generic so it can be reused easily.

Thus we get:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
    func countOfAjacentDifferingElements() -> Int {
        return zip(self, self.dropFirst())
            .lazy
            .map { $0 == $1 ? 1 : 0 }
            .reduce(0, +)
    }
}

let numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
print(numbers.countOfAjacentDifferingElements()) // => 2
```

Comment: but [0 0 1 0 0 1 0] gives 2 instead of 4

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand why should it give 4. There's only 2 pairs of adjacent equal elements, shown here with brackets: `[(0 0) 1 (0 0) 1 0]`

Comment: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], a to b, b to d, d to e, e to g]

Comment: Oh so you're counting pairs of different elements? In that case, you can just switch around the `0` and the `1`, so the count gets incremented when `==` returns false: `$0 == $1 ? 0 : 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let c: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

var counter  = 0

var lastIndexOfZero = 0

for index in 1..<c.count {

    if c[lastIndexOfZero] == c[index] {
        counter += 1
    }

    if c[index] == 0 {
        lastIndexOfZero = index
    }
}

print(counter)
```

Or you can simply do

```
// in case your first number is 1
print(c.filter({ $0 == c[0] }).count-1)
```

Comment: I updated the question. it does not return the right output

Comment: @King It Does i just changed your array form [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] to [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: @King Change it to what ever you want

Comment: try [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: @King This should and is returning 2, you give it a try.

Comment: 2 is not correct it is suppose to return 4

Comment: @King please update the question as per your question it should return 2 as only index 0 and index 1 are same and index 3 and 4.

Comment: yes i updated the question

Comment: @King edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :).

```
let numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

let count = numbers.enumerated().reduce(0) { result, tuple in
    let nextOffset = tuple.offset + 1

    guard
        nextOffset < numbers.count,
        numbers[nextOffset] == tuple.element
    else {
        return result
    }

    return result + 1
}

print(count)
```

This will return `3` for your array.

Comment: if the array is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], it retuns 2 which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
let c: [Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

let numberOfCycles = c.count-2

var count = 0
for i in 0...numberOfCycles {
    if c[i] == c[i+1] {
        count += 1
    }
}

print(count)
```

Comment: it is the same issue, if the array is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], it retuns 2 which is wrong and it should be 4

Comment: Why it should be 4? The index found are 0 and 3, what other indexes should increase the counter?

Comment: since index 2 is 3 , you compare index 1 to index 4

Comment: I don't understand what your asking sorry, index 2 = 1 and I'm not comparing index 1 to index 4. I think you should reformulate what you're trying to achieve